# How to pad a sequence for CNN architecture?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to apply CNN (convolutional neural network) for regression on time series using Conv1D. The architecture is as follows:

```
filters = 100

model_attn = Sequential()
model_attn.add(Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=15, activation='relu', input_shape=(complete_inputs.shape[1], complete_inputs.shape[2])))
model_attn.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=None))
model_attn.add(Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=15, activation='relu', input_shape=(complete_inputs.shape[1], complete_inputs.shape[2])))
model_attn.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=None))
model_attn.add(Flatten())
model_attn.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model_attn.add(Dense(1))
model_attn.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(0.0001), loss ='mae')
```

The data I have is of the form of a large number of time series of variable length. I am also applying the StandardScaler() to normalize the input.

The problem I am facing is that in order to make each time series of the input of uniform length to feed the CNN, I have to pad the input. When I pad the input (which has the varying lengths of time series) and THEN apply the normalization, the zeros turn into floats, and each float value is significantly different even though all those floats are supposed to represent zero (0). I'm afraid that this might be the reason of the huge losses of the CNN (loss, val_loss > 0.4) no matter what changes I make to the hyperparameters.

(I cannot apply normalization before padding, since this gives me an error)

The data is of the form (one sample shown):

```
array([0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 1.0706892, 1.0744922,
   1.0758405, 1.0766355, 1.0765879, 1.0766382, 1.0768414, 1.0767081,
   1.0765858, 1.0765196, 1.0763972, 1.0762045, 1.0760512, 1.0759902,
   1.0759126], dtype=float32)
```

After scaling, the data becomes:

```
array([-0.0098773 , -0.01396927, -0.01710961, -0.01975744, -0.02209057,
   -0.02420019, -0.02614048, -0.02794671, -0.02964341, -0.03124843,
   -0.03277523, -0.03563382, -0.0382806 , -0.0407568 , -0.04309184,
   -0.04530753, -0.04742062, -0.04944426, -0.05138901, -0.05326353,
   -0.05507497, -0.05682939, -0.05853189, -0.0601869 , -0.06179822,
   -0.06336918, -0.06490272, -0.06640144, -0.06786764, -0.06930339,
   -0.07071052, -0.07209074, -0.07344555, -0.07477634, -0.07608435,
   -0.07737076, -0.07863662, -0.0798829 , -0.08111052, -0.0823203 ,
   -0.08351303, -0.08468941, -0.08585013, -0.08699582, -0.08812705,
   -0.08924437, -0.0903483 , -0.09143934, -0.09251794, -0.09358452,
   -0.09463949, -0.09568325, -0.09671614, -0.09773852, -0.0987507 ,
   -0.10025053, -0.10172912, -0.10366905, -0.10557488, -0.10744838,
   -0.1092912 , -0.11110488, -0.11333311, -0.11552052, -0.11766941,
   -0.1197818 , -0.12185962, -0.12390462, -0.12591837, -0.12790239,
   -0.129858  , -0.13178651, -0.13368906, -0.13556679, -0.13742065,
   -0.13961521, -0.14177836, -0.14391151, -0.146016  , -0.14809306,
   -0.1501438 , -0.15216932, -0.15417059, -0.15614858, -0.15810414,
   -0.16035835, -0.16258444, -0.16478348, -0.1669566 , -0.16910481,
   -0.17122902, -0.17333013, -0.17540897, -0.17746635, -0.179503  ,
   -0.18151961, -0.18351686, -0.18549539, -0.18745577, -0.18939863,
   -0.19132444, -0.19323374, -0.19512701, -0.19700477, -0.19886741,
   -0.20071536, -0.20254904, -0.20436884, -0.20617515, -0.20796828,
   -0.20974864, -0.2115165 , -0.2132722 , -0.21501584, -0.21699467,
   -0.2189588 , -0.22090861, -0.22284448, -0.22476685, -0.226676  ,
   -0.2285723 , -0.23045607, -0.23232761, -0.23418722, -0.23603524,
   -0.23787189, -0.23969747, -0.24151221, -0.24331637, -0.24511018,
   -0.24689364, -0.24866745, -0.25043166, -0.2521862 , -0.2539317 ,
   -0.2556681 , -0.25761104, -0.25954303, -0.2614643 , -0.26337513,
   -0.2652757 , -0.26716635, -0.26904663, -0.27091795, -0.2727799 ,
   -0.27463275, -0.27647632, -0.27831146, -0.28013793, -0.281956  ,
   -0.28376585, -0.28556734, -0.28736123, -0.2891473 , -0.29132003,
   -0.29367775, -0.29602244, -0.29835477, -0.30067492, -0.3029831 ,
   -0.30527973, -0.30756497, -0.30983916, -0.31229043, -0.31472957,
   -0.317343  , -0.32012805, -0.32308212, -0.32601935, -0.32948637,
   -0.33293125, -0.33653453, -0.34029344, -0.34402823, -0.347916  ,
   -0.35195422, -0.35614058, -0.36030012, -0.36460558, -0.36888412,
   -0.37313697, -0.37753382, -0.38190514, -0.38625202, -0.3905755 ,
   -0.3952066 , -0.39981288, -0.4045587 , -0.4094427 , -0.41430196,
   -0.41913772, -0.42395112, -0.42874327, -0.43351525, -0.4387422 ,
   -0.44410446, -0.4497582 , -0.45570102, -0.46177515, -0.4679805 ,
   -0.47416276, -0.48063117, -0.48738453, -0.49426895, -0.50113285,
   -0.50797826, -0.51480716, -0.5220752 , -0.5293287 , -0.5365699 ,
   -0.5438007 , -0.5510232 , -0.55838937, -0.565901  , -0.5734096 ,
   -0.5812176 , -0.5890266 , -0.596989  , -0.6051072 , -0.613685  ,
   -0.6224249 , -0.63117915, -0.6399503 , -0.64874095, -0.6577059 ,
   -0.6666962 , -0.67571455, -0.68491715, -0.6943084 , -0.7037379 ,
   -0.71336436, -0.72319263, -0.73307097, -0.7430025 , -0.75330853,
   -0.7636781 , -0.77411455, -0.78462166, -0.79520303, -0.80635613,
   -0.81759876, -0.8294377 , -0.84172213, -0.8546382 , -0.86838096,
   -0.88280624, -0.897588  , -0.9129222 , -0.92883426, -0.94590706,
   -0.96363425, -0.9816685 , -1.0002222 , -1.0191268 , -1.0384021 ,
   -1.0582769 , -1.0785757 , -1.0993239 , -1.1205478 , -1.1422764 ,
   -1.1645403 , -1.1873723 , -1.2108079 , -1.2348853 , -1.2596458 ,
   -1.2851342 , -1.311399  , -1.3387773 , -1.3670616 , -1.3963174 ,
   -1.4266162 , -1.4580369 , -1.491006  , -1.5253086 , -1.5610552 ,
   -1.5983696 , -1.6373909 , -1.6782749 , -1.7211987 , -1.7663625 ,
   -1.8139961 , -1.8643622 , -1.9177647 , -1.9745562 , -2.03515   ,
   -2.1000326 , -2.1697834 , -2.2450805 , -2.3267937 , -2.4159408 ,
   -2.5137994 , -2.6219797 , -2.7425473 , -2.8781922 , -3.032506  ,
   -3.212353  , -3.4234576 , -3.676436  , -3.9877586 , -4.3847356 ,
   -4.916755  , -5.685551  , -6.9478936 , -9.667068  ,  0.7664037 ,
    0.8944819 ,  0.9429276 ,  0.972402  ,  0.97564405,  0.9807707 ,
    0.98882246,  0.9867822 ,  0.9841371 ,  0.9820615 ,  0.9778804 ,
    0.9715033 ,  0.96555257,  0.9610835 ,  0.95586026], dtype=float32)
```

Is there a solution to the problem?

**EDIT 1:** Although I have applied inverse_transform to the scaled input to get back the original input, would the CNN recognise the difference?

inverse_transform of the same input looks like:

```
array([-3.82500585e-12, -6.33975728e-12,  4.86057548e-12,  5.84291122e-12,
   -3.65678798e-12, -7.03534193e-12, -2.00839432e-11,  1.29974963e-11,
   -2.88795394e-11,  3.08669236e-11, -1.98511346e-11,  6.40846404e-11,
   -5.68959879e-11,  1.49610324e-10, -8.36972922e-11,  5.78726442e-11,
    2.94587202e-11, -9.54626100e-11,  1.46498647e-11,  1.31735204e-12,
    3.80215096e-11, -9.32821598e-11, -1.02480913e-10,  9.24872123e-11,
   -1.94741001e-10,  1.29327646e-10,  2.05188963e-10,  9.56670229e-11,
    1.42319462e-10,  7.77692077e-11, -2.21269739e-10, -7.73603681e-11,
   -2.09277290e-10, -1.77569986e-10,  1.89698715e-10, -1.72346012e-10,
   -5.98804728e-10,  5.97441929e-10, -1.12701751e-10,  1.23831112e-10,
   -3.82940658e-11,  2.25948621e-10, -4.22097801e-10, -4.23188040e-10,
   -4.58075161e-10, -4.29729363e-10,  1.51722628e-11,  3.02445902e-10,
    1.44000228e-10, -2.06233763e-11,  3.57047863e-10,  3.83576615e-10,
   -3.20343724e-10, -2.94996028e-10,  4.12376661e-10,  1.87154858e-11,
    3.96114183e-11,  1.57900554e-10,  6.75029477e-11, -1.75980078e-10,
   -8.18575416e-11, -2.18953015e-11, -4.28820840e-10,  3.64134306e-10,
   -3.55685092e-10, -3.42148171e-10, -6.85023149e-10, -5.14039922e-10,
   -2.07142276e-10, -1.72618558e-10,  4.33545144e-10,  3.73764630e-10,
    2.45481774e-10, -2.50623988e-09,  4.42630321e-10,  7.42441553e-10,
   -8.48374815e-10,  4.90418428e-10,  9.20692911e-10,  5.92172533e-10,
   -6.45593412e-10, -7.53888840e-10, -7.12278708e-11, -8.05674416e-10,
    3.04717196e-10,  5.20762933e-10, -2.71919665e-09,  1.05351838e-09,
    5.64371827e-10, -2.34652231e-09,  8.39289638e-10, -1.52522128e-09,
   -1.00300469e-10, -7.48619444e-10,  4.13557744e-10,  9.73932046e-10,
   -9.55034940e-10, -2.94360092e-10,  1.52158719e-09, -1.37549738e-09,
   -1.66622338e-09, -3.79760834e-10, -4.34635383e-10, -4.57530042e-10,
   -1.04915743e-09,  2.25312657e-10,  1.21741506e-10,  6.23607277e-10,
    9.34684108e-10,  4.98595110e-10, -1.33879319e-09, -7.09734826e-10,
    7.52980345e-10,  1.54484525e-09,  1.57791535e-09, -9.04884709e-11,
   -1.83302740e-09,  1.51904334e-09, -1.72618564e-09, -6.61401628e-11,
    1.76834092e-09, -1.14073617e-09, -1.19924473e-10,  1.18834254e-09,
   -3.17254750e-10,  1.04661363e-10,  1.64914327e-09, -6.59584609e-10,
    3.73219511e-10,  8.87441121e-10,  1.23667576e-09, -8.79446183e-10,
   -1.89480676e-09, -2.89853830e-09, -1.63388014e-09, -1.72109793e-09,
    1.13165100e-09, -2.22405386e-10, -2.18989360e-09, -6.63582078e-10,
   -6.19973184e-10, -3.31645689e-09,  1.02044828e-09, -2.49879006e-09,
    6.13431861e-10,  2.10994400e-09, -1.56265223e-10, -9.91230298e-09,
   -1.19706434e-09, -1.42746470e-09, -1.82793969e-09,  1.88971894e-11,
   -3.33535399e-09, -6.66634703e-09, -5.93081029e-10,  6.06890538e-10,
   -2.73064393e-09,  3.93206911e-10, -1.15563581e-09,  3.15146975e-09,
    2.42538167e-09, -6.44757581e-09, -7.41714690e-09,  3.42475226e-09,
    3.36951445e-09, -9.03285713e-09, -5.45111245e-09, -6.62128463e-10,
   -2.85056845e-09,  2.67904010e-09, -1.51250201e-09,  3.95605415e-09,
    5.75637493e-09, -1.88899230e-09, -9.44641432e-09,  3.56212038e-09,
   -6.41777631e-10, -1.13455823e-09,  8.15777135e-09,  5.65316727e-09,
    7.29431537e-09,  2.55838878e-10,  6.90474233e-10,  4.47863391e-09,
    3.82450072e-09, -1.76470683e-09, -7.01812564e-09, -3.60936325e-09,
   -6.45557074e-09, -6.56023236e-09,  5.43657608e-09,  5.52088686e-09,
    5.35371925e-09, -3.79106702e-09, -6.31747588e-09,  2.36214870e-09,
    9.89922033e-10, -1.31989608e-09,  1.30390609e-09,  3.41748407e-09,
   -5.90755223e-09, -4.75482365e-09, -7.15767401e-09, -3.10350012e-09,
    6.51662324e-09,  3.28375016e-09,  2.29092079e-09,  1.61847158e-08,
    1.31655273e-08,  1.13906449e-08,  1.81921802e-08,  4.79261830e-09,
   -5.14585041e-10,  1.09312976e-08, -1.63388014e-09,  1.13935519e-08,
    1.11086402e-08, -8.55025206e-09,  9.73932046e-10, -8.57641691e-09,
    3.19217142e-09, -8.33220692e-09,  1.19197665e-08,  1.36234206e-08,
   -2.44209852e-09, -8.97761865e-09, -9.24508647e-09,  1.43705865e-08,
   -1.16929995e-08, -2.40139686e-09, -6.85241197e-09,  2.21823937e-09,
    2.56129606e-09, -1.03411235e-08,  3.67186948e-09, -7.72749686e-09,
   -2.32290076e-09,  1.03731033e-08, -9.31486088e-09, -1.06144062e-08,
    1.29663800e-08, -3.61663144e-09, -2.77061885e-09, -5.03246689e-09,
    5.50344303e-09, -3.77653064e-09, -2.72700995e-09,  1.99438044e-09,
    6.62855271e-10,  1.87460127e-08,  8.40198133e-09, -2.32580799e-09,
    2.84504473e-08, -6.45411724e-09,  1.45944448e-08,  8.91365914e-09,
   -2.40430396e-08, -1.45130423e-08, -1.65190510e-08,  4.16319645e-09,
    1.67923346e-08, -4.71557549e-09, -1.79552373e-08, -2.52931613e-08,
   -1.19197663e-09, -6.83787560e-09,  1.06405720e-08,  1.90309244e-08,
   -1.81180440e-08, -1.86646094e-08,  7.29140837e-09,  3.01192138e-09,
   -1.41350984e-08,  1.36350495e-08,  1.10475877e-08, -1.94728269e-08,
    2.68165667e-08, -2.88458342e-08, -6.86113388e-10, -2.10485620e-08,
    1.63969460e-08,  2.59909037e-08,  2.01124255e-08, -6.39015774e-09,
   -5.66741249e-08,  7.72691564e-08,  1.54956954e-08,  2.57583235e-08,
    2.15137241e-08, -3.31427641e-09, -2.13974332e-08, -1.70656165e-08,
   -6.40178666e-09,  7.01696266e-08,  5.68078597e-08, -2.80841306e-09,
   -2.96714955e-08,  5.96569727e-09, -2.45023877e-08,  1.41118406e-08,
   -1.15069350e-08,  2.51129126e-08,  4.52718538e-08,  3.16309889e-09,
    1.07068920e+00,  1.07449222e+00,  1.07584047e+00,  1.07663548e+00,
    1.07658792e+00,  1.07663822e+00,  1.07684135e+00,  1.07670808e+00,
    1.07658577e+00,  1.07651961e+00,  1.07639718e+00,  1.07620454e+00,
    1.07605124e+00,  1.07599020e+00,  1.07591259e+00], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: padding doesn't mean padding all with 0, you can also pad with the last valuable element of your sequences

Comment: Is there a possible way to pad with a non-numeric data WITHOUT any errors, such that both the StandardScaler as well as the CNN network ignores them completely?

Comment: sklearn scalers accepts only numeric data so you can't... I suggest you to pad repeating the last element

Comment: Or correspondingly the first element? (since it is 'pre' padding that I am applying here)

Comment: yes... the logic is the same

Comment: While we're on topic, is there any way around padding for CNNs? Or is padding compulsory for variable length sequences?

Comment: yes, all the inputs must have the same dimensions, no way around